# How can I build a filter in React with the Autocomplete component from MaterialUI using state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I am building a filter with the [Autocomplete component from MaterialUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#limit-tags). When selecting options from the dropdown:

- The `Autocomplete` component also will append to the [Chip Array](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/#chip-array) as options are selected.
- The value of that option is added to an array `filter` in the state object.

Through the `event` object from the `onChange` prop, I can successfully add this value to the array using `event.target.textContent`. When trying to handle removing elements however, things haven't felt as straight forward but I'm likely missing something.

There is an `onDelete` prop within each `Chip` component - this (and others) can be accessed through the prop `ChipProps` in `Autocomplete`. Without touching the `onDelete` prop, the `Chip` from the filter is removed, but the array `results` from the current state is not going to be updated.

The example code from [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/#chip-array) seems to do what I would like but this is using just `Chip` components by maping through the `Chips` to create and passing each one through its own respective `onDelete`. I don't see how to do that with the `Autocomplete` where the `Chips` are populated outside of that context.

Any help here would be appreciated and please go easy as I am new to React...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding a second parameter to the `onChange` function as this apparently holds the value when used. Docs didn't seem to mention this in the examples. Would love to learn more about it if anyone knows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).